# Is it possible to initialize the template inner class in the C++20 requires clause?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following class `A` that defines a template inner class `B`:

```
struct A {
  template<class = int>
  struct B { };
};
```

We can use the following expression to initialize inner `B`, where `typename` is *optional*: ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/76KdjMc1q))

```
int main() {
  A::template B<>();
  typename A::template B<>();
}
```

I want to use `concept` to detect whether a type has a template inner class `B`:

```
template<class T>
concept C = requires {
  typename T::template B<>();
};

static_assert(C<A>);
```

But only Clang accepted the above code, GCC and MSVC rejected it due to syntax error ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xzb9doe4q)):

```
<source>:8:27: error: expected ';' before '(' token
    8 |   typename T::template B<>();
      |                           ^
      |                           ;
```

And if I remove the `typename` in the `require` clause:

```
template<class T>
concept C = requires {
  T::template B<>();
};
```

MSVC accepted it, but Clang and GCC will produce `static assertion failed` since they think the expression is not well-formed ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GrGePrh5E)):

```
<source>:11:15: note: because 'A' does not satisfy 'C'
static_assert(C<A>);
              ^
<source>:8:15: note: because 'T::template B<>()' would be invalid: 'A::B' instantiated to a class template, not a function template
  T::template B<>();
              ^
```

Which compiler should I trust?

Comment: `template` is unnecessary in `A::template` because `A` is not dependent.  You can omit the `()` from the requirements to at least make them syntactically valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of concepts is, that if you want to check such cases, you have to use the compound statement.

```
struct A 
{
    template<class = int>
        struct B { };
};

template<class T>
concept C = requires 
{
    { typename T::template B<>() };
};

static_assert(C<A>);
```

I believe you can't use it within a `simple requirement` clause, because `T::template B<>` is a dependent name and needs the keyword `typename` in front because the concept itself is a template and you are sitting in a unevaluated context.

If you are using the keyword `typename` in front, it is not longer a `simple requirement` but becomes a `type requirement`. But this one checks for the existence of the type and is not intended to build a expression to instantiate the type.

As this you end up in a compound expression where you are able to get the type with keyword `typename` in the dependent template and do the default initialization of that type.

As alternative, shown as `C2`, you can pick your type upfront in the concept template parameter list which enables you to use the found type without the keyword `typename` in the `simple requires clause`.

I also added test cases to see the concept failing by "killing" the default constructor of your inner type `B`.

```
struct A 
{
    template<class = int>
        struct B { };
};

struct A2  
{
    template<class = int>
        struct B { B()=delete; };
};


template<class T>
concept C = requires 
{
    { typename T::template B<>() };
};


template<class T, typename Inner = typename T::template B<> >
concept C2 = requires 
{
    Inner();
};


static_assert(C<A>);
static_assert(C<A2>); // fails as expected

static_assert(C2<A>);
static_assert(C2<A2>); // fails as expected
```

The above code works for all your three given compilers: [explore](https://godbolt.org/z/6vjK3PP58)